# Can I modify a Xcode Build Settings from a cordova plugin's plugin.xml?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, plugins

I am creating a custom Cordova plugin that requires some custom Xcode Build Settings to be specified (for example, `CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD`).

I thought I would be able to set it using the `config.xml` specs of the [cordova-custom-config plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) as follows:

```
 <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" value="gnu++0x" quote="none" buildType="release" /> 
 <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" value="gnu++0x" quote="none" buildType="debug" /> 
 <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" value="libc++" quote="none" buildType="release" /> 
 <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" value="libc++" quote="none" buildType="debug" /> 
 <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" value="gnu99" quote="none" buildType="release" /> 
 <custom-preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" value="gnu99" quote="none" buildType="debug"/>
```

However, when installing the plugin with `plugman install` they are not applied.

Any suggestion on how to modify Xcode Build Settings from a Cordova plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add build flags to the build.json

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "development",
            "buildFlag": [
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
                "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
            ]
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "FG35JLLMXX4A",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "buildFlag": [
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
                "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#using-buildjson

Comment: For others like me wondering where the `build.json` goes, it is in the project root folder